# Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

I keep getting this error and for the life of me, I don't know why! "Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined" the changeData validator works, but the validator for the ChangePasswordForm form is not working.

```
<form [formGroup]="changedataForm" (ngSubmit)="changeData()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUsername">Username: </label>
                        <input class="input1" matInput type="text" id="username"  [(ngModel)]="username" autocomplete="off" formControlName="username" required>
                            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf ="f.username.invalid && (f.username.dirty || f.username.touched)" style="font-size: small;">Username is already taken</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col" style="right:-100px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUsername">Email: </label>
                        <input class="input1" matInput type="text" id="email" [(ngModel)]="email" autocomplete="off" formControlName="email" required>
                        <div class="text-danger" *ngIf ="f.email.invalid && (f.email.dirty || f.email.touched)" style="font-size: small;">Please use another email</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUsername">First Name: </label>
                        <input class="input1" matInput type="text" id="first_name" [(ngModel)]="first_name" formControlName="first_name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col" style="right:-100px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUsername">Last Name: </label>
                        <input class="input1" matInput type="text" id="first_name" [(ngModel)]="last_name" formControlName="last_name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!changedataForm.valid">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

The warning text for the second form is not activating. Both forms share an HTML card, sorry for the spacing issues. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
<div class="card-header">
    <h5 class="card-title mb-0">Password Change</h5>
</div>
<br>
<form [formGroup]="changePasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="ChangePassword()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">                                    
                        <label for="inputUsername">Old Password: </label>
                        <input class="input1" matInput type="password" id="old_password"  autocomplete="off" formControlName="old_password" required>
                    </div>
                    <label class="badge" style="align-items: left;">Password</label>
                    <input class="input1" matInput type="password" id="new_password1" placeholder="" formControlName="new_password1" required>
                    <div class="text-danger" *ngIf ="f.new_password1.invalid && (f.new_password1.dirty || f.new_password1.touched)" style="font-size: small;">Password must be 8 Characters long</div>
                                                
                                                
                        <label class="badge" style="align-items: left;">Password2</label>
                        <input class="input1" matInput type="password" id="new_password2" placeholder=""  formControlName="new_password2" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col" style="right:-200px;"></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
         </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!changePasswordForm.valid">Save changes</button>
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: try to add  [(ngModel)] for changePasswordForm

Comment: `f.username.invalid` what is `f`?  would you please post your component code?

Comment: @RafiHenig you helped me realize I was pointing at the wrong form controls! Thank you